# Einstein Bot to Auto End Session if Idle

Tags: chat, einstein-chatbot, service, einstein-bots, slack

I'm currently using Einstein Bots to make the user interact with the bot through Slack.

Is there a way to make an Einstein Bot automatically end the chat session if customer is idle, or end the session automatically after maybe 10 minutes? I only know that an Einstein Bot has the `End Chat` dialog to end the chat session, but it requires a customer input. My case is if the customer idle and not giving any input.

Answer (score 2):

If you can associate the Einstein bot with a Chat Button, then you can setup time-out under the chat button settings.
(To add a chat button to a bot, go to add connection section under overview page for the Einstein Bot)

In CRM setup, look for "Chat Buttons", open the chat button settings associated with the Bot.

Activate option `Enable Customer Time-Out` and add `Customer Time-Out (seconds)` and `Customer Time-Out Warning (seconds)`.

During a chat, a warning message is displayed when `Customer Time-Out Warning (seconds)` is reached and after `Customer Time-Out (seconds)`, the chat is closed automatically if customer does not provide any input.

Note that Time-out warning duration must be less than Time-out duration.

See screenshot below for illustration, adjust the duration in seconds as per your requirement.

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: i tried this, but the time out warning message didnt show on slack. Is there any configuration i need to do in slack?

Comment: @AriefGunawanTjiptorahardja not sure additional configuration is needed for slack. does the timeout work in Einstein bot preview mode ?

Comment: Not working in bot preview mode also

Comment: Strange, because I could test the time out in preview mode. Did you associate the chat button in the overview page of the Einstein bot? Could you edit your question and provide some screenshot of the button and bot overview settings?